# Read content from all sub-directories

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to reading content from all sub-directories but I only gets the content of first file in last directory. I am trying the following code:

```
content= []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('test_group'):
    for file in files:
        with open(os.path.join(root,file), "r") as text:
            content = text.read()
            
print(content)
```

Then I tried this code and it only gives empty list:

```
content= []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('test_group'):
    for dirname in dirs:
        for file in files:
            with open(os.path.join(root,file), "r") as text:
                content = text.read()
            
print(content)
```

My parent directory name is 'test_group'. And inside it has 9 sub-directories. Each sub directory has approximately 20 text files in each. Now I want to read the data from all files of all sub directories and append it to the content list. I am beginner and do not know where I am doing mistake. Please guide me where I am doing mistake. I would be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my first code as follow and it worked for me.

```
content= []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('test_group'):
    for file in files:
        with open(os.path.join(root,file), "r") as text:
            content.append(text.read()) 
            
print(content)
```

Firstly, I guess it is overwriting the text. And when I append it then it saves the data.